# Quartz.net IJobDetails using manually created IJob realizations

Tags: constructor, castle-windsor, jobs, quartz.net, parameterized

I've got a problem using Quartz.net. There is restriction on IJob, this objects have to be costructed via parameterless constructor.
 But I need to use them with parameters.
 Can I create Job istances from already instantiated IJob classes.
 I use windsor to create such classes.

Comment: Consider posting this to the Castle-users list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/castle-project-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using Windsor to create your Job instance, you can pass parameter constructor as per any other instance created through the IoC container.
Since IoC is in control of creating job instance, creation depends on how you registered it into the container.

If for example, your job contructor parameters are other object/component instances, they have to be registered into the container as well.
If they are static parameters you may use "DependsOn" when you register you component into the container...

Comment: That's true. But quartz.net doesn't use instances, instead it creates instances of it's own, and this instances have to be constructed via parameterless constructor. But I want to replace them with IoC's instances and don't know how.

Comment: I used Mauricio Facility until I was on version 1.x
http://bugsquash.blogspot.it/2009/03/windsor-facility-for-quartznet.html

Comment: Since I switched to 2.0 I built my own windsor factory based on IJobFactory
http://thecodesaysitall.blogspot.it/2012/02/integrate-quartznet-with-your-favourite.html

Comment: Temporarly made some kind of facade pattern for jobs, to much changes with custom factory. But later will implement it. Thanks.

Comment: The Quartz-Windsor facility is built for Quartz.NET 2 since 0.2.0 http://nuget.org/packages/Quartz.Windsor . Next time please consider contributing to a community effort instead of rewriting the whole thing from scratch.

Comment: @Mauricio you're absolutly right, but I did not re-wrote the whole thing. Our team created a simple windsor factory w/ decomission concern since at that time there was not facility for Quartz2.0. We really apprechiate your effort maintaining the quarz facility

Answer (score 2):

I don't know [quartz.net](/questions/tagged/quartz.net) much, but seems like you can plug-in your own [`IJobFactory`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/topic2882.html) implementation. The same approach works great with [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) framework and [`SpringBeanJobFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SpringBeanJobFactory.html).

Comment: That doesn't actually works for me, cuz there is a little different mechanism.